# A JSlider with both minor and major labels?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

Is it possible for both **minor** and **major** ticking labels to be displayed on the same `JSlider`?

Comment: `JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0, 30, 15); slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);slider.setPaintTicks(true);slider.setPaintLabels(true);` will show min label 0 and max label 30 with slider at 15. The major and minor ticking labels can be shown together at the given interval settings with major ticks occur at every 10 and minor ticks occur at every 1

Comment: The question **also needs votes** ;-) Not only the answer...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible (though might not look very nice) - you can add labels at arbitrary positions, see

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html